# Python OpenCV/NumPy: why np.uint8([255]) + np.uint8([255]) is giving result 254 instead of 255?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, opencv

```
import numpy as np

a = np.uint8([255])
b = np.uint8([255])

print(a+b)
```

**Result:** array([254], dtype=uint8)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering why it's giving 254 instead of 255 @user_na

Comment: Because `uint8` wraps at 256; you get (255+255)-256.

Comment: Research a bit on Integer overflow. In `unit8` `255+1 = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uint8 can save the range 0..255 .

So example you write `np.uint8([256])` -> `array([0], dtype=uint8)`

In your case `a+b=np.uint8([510])=np.uint8([510-256])=np.uint8([254])`

Comment: Thank You! That Helps.

Answer (score 1):

`uint8` is an unsigned integer represented using 8 bits. The range of numbers you can represent using 8 bits is [0, 255].

255 in 8-bit binary is 1111 1111.

When you add 1111 1111 to 1111 1111, you get 1 1111 1110 (= 510). But since you have only 8 bits to represent (since you're using `uint8`), the leftmost 1 in the result cannot be stored, rendering the result as 1111 1110, which is 254.

Comment: Thank You! That Helps.